# Android Studio: build.gradle (project) not visible in "Project"

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to rebuild an old (working) project in AndroidStudio. It builds Ok but strangely, the project's build.gradle is *not* visible in the AS Project tab.
Note that the *module's* build.gradle appears but not the *project's* build.gradle.

[image]

Both files ARE indeed there

```
Directory of C:\dev\AndroidProjects\apps\Passwords\app
11/09/2020  04:16 PM               767 build.gradle
               1 File(s)            767 bytes
 Directory of C:\dev\AndroidProjects\apps\Passwords
11/09/2020  03:13 PM               352 build.gradle
               1 File(s)            352 bytes
```

The project otherwise builds just fine.
The projects build.gradle IS active: If I make changes to it outside AS using a text editor, the changes DO take effect.

**What I've Tried:**
Restart PC and AS
Cleaned/Rebuilt Project
Invalidate Caches & Restart
Searched SO for problem. Question 47406517 was similar but solution didn't work
Copy build.gradle from another known-good project.

**Notes:**
Android Studio: V3.6.3
PC: Win10-64
Project Name: "Passwords"

I'm at a loss for other things to try. **Any suggestions?**
(I guess as a work-around, I can always use an external text editor but that's annoying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in SO question #46230078. The solution was simple: Close AndroidStudio, delete the directory "**.idea**" from the project directory, restart AndroidStudio.  This did it!